# Create Queue Manager in a Declared Host

Tags: c#, message-queue, ibm-mq

In C#, using IBM WebSphere MQ, I run:

```
var properties = new Hashtable();
properties.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, someHostName);
var queueManager = MQQueueManager(someQueueNameManager, properties);
```

I get an exception:

```
System.Exception: Channel and Connection MUST be specified
```

Obviously, it wants me to specify the channel. But I don't want to specify the channel. Is it important to specify it? I mean, When I run

```
var queueManager = MQQueueManager(someQueueNameManager);
```

It works and connects to the local MQ. How can I create an MQQueueManager object that connects to a queue manager in a different host without specifying any channel? If specifying a channel is necessary, please explain why that is the case.

Comment: "If specifying a channel is necessary, please explain why that is the case."  @Umapathy was more generous than I would have been with an answer like "because that's the way the product works."  A more charitable answer from me might be to suggest clicking on the [tag:websphere-mq] tag and reading the tag wiki.  There are many references in there to free downloads, documentation, tutorials and more.  If the MQ Primer Umapathy pointed to is not already listed, I'll add it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a MQI Channel (Server Conn or Server Conn & Client Conn) to connect to a remote queue manager (ie a qmgr running on a remote host) over the network.  The channel connects to the qmgr and puts/gets the messages for you.  For a local qmgr, you can connect in bindings mode (and that's what you have done). This mode bypasses the network stack and connects to the qmgr using shared memory and semaphores.

This is one of the basic technical concept in IBM MQ. I suggest reading the MQ primer.  It's small and covers all you need to know about MQ before using it.

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp0021.pdf